# Extracting an internal JSON object from another JSON object

Tags: json, api, twitter, dart, flutter

I'm trying to show a list of tweets using [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline), using the `fromJson` factory.

Each `tweet` object has an `extended_entities` object which is an array of `media` objects.

If you're not familiar with the [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline) you can see all the different objects [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/intro-to-tweet-json).

Here are the models i created in order to achieve this:

```
class Tweet {
  final String createdAt;
  final int id;
  final String idStr;
  final String text;
  final String inReplyToStatusIdStr;
  final String inReplyToUserIdStr;
  final TweetExtendedEntities tweetExtendedEntities;

  Tweet(
      {this.createdAt,
      this.id,
      this.idStr,
      this.text,
      this.inReplyToStatusIdStr,
      this.inReplyToUserIdStr,
      this.tweetExtendedEntities});

  factory Tweet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Tweet(
      createdAt: json['created_at'] as String,
      id: json['id'] as int,
      idStr: json['id_str'] as String,
      text: json['text'] as String,
      inReplyToStatusIdStr: json['in_reply_to_status_id_str'] as String,
      inReplyToUserIdStr: json['in_reply_to_user_id_str'] as String,
      tweetExtendedEntities: json['extended_entities'] as TweetExtendedEntities,
    );
  }
}

class TweetExtendedEntities {
  final List<TweetMedia> tweetMedia;

  TweetExtendedEntities({this.tweetMedia});

  factory TweetExtendedEntities.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new TweetExtendedEntities(
        tweetMedia: json['media'] as List<TweetMedia>);
  }
}

class TweetMedia {
  final String mediaType;
  final String mediaUrl;

  TweetMedia({this.mediaType, this.mediaUrl});

  factory TweetMedia.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new TweetMedia(
      mediaType: json['type'] as String,
      mediaUrl: json['media_url'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Before i tried to get the `extended_entities` object everything was fine and i successfully got the JSON data and parsed it, but when i try to get the `media` objects using the code above, i get this error:

```
I/flutter (29538): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'TweetExtendedEntities' in type cast where
I/flutter (29538):   _InternalLinkedHashMap is from dart:collection
I/flutter (29538):   String is from dart:core
I/flutter (29538):   TweetExtendedEntities is from package:pubg_companion/models/tweet.dart
```

How can i get nested JSON objects using `factory` or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart has no idea that your JSON structure will correspond to your object, or how.  You can't directly cast the JSON (which is probably a `Map<String, dynamic>`, but could also be other things) to your objects.  @betorcs answer is a start in the right direction but needs a bit more.

This line:

```
tweetExtendedEntities: json['extended_entities'] as TweetExtendedEntities,
```

Needs to be

```
tweetExtendedEntities: TweetExtendedEntities.fromJson['extended_entities'],
```

And your `TweetExtendedEntities` method should look more like this:

```
factory TweetExtendedEntities.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return new TweetExtendedEntities(
      tweetMedia: createTweetMediaList(json['media']));
}

static List<TweetMedia> createTweetMediaList(List json) {
  if (json == null) return null;
  if (json.isEmpty) return [];

  return json.map((tweetMediaJson) => TweetMedia.fromJson(tweetMediaJson)).toList();
}
```

You could also certainly look into [json_serializable](https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable) if your needs start getting more complicated and you want to try to generate some of this code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `json` parameter is  `Map<String, dynamic>`, `dynamic` is not `TweetExtendedEntities`, but it can be cast to `Map`.

```
factory Tweet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Tweet(
      createdAt: json['created_at'] as String,
      id: json['id'] as int,
      idStr: json['id_str'] as String,
      text: json['text'] as String,
      inReplyToStatusIdStr: json['in_reply_to_status_id_str'] as String,
      inReplyToUserIdStr: json['in_reply_to_user_id_str'] as String,
      tweetExtendedEntities: TweetExtendedEntities.fromJson(json['extended_entities'] as Map),
    );
  }
```

Comment: OP also has to do something similar in `TweetExtendedEntities.fromJson` - can't cast it directly to a `List<TweetMedia>`.  This answer would be a bit more helpful if it at least pointed out how that might work

Answer (score 0):

In flutter, this error will be thrown when you pass a string without json.decode() to the fromjson factory

eg:

```
Map bodyJson = json.decode(loginResponse.body);
var login = new LoginResponse.fromJson(bodyJson);
```

The LoginResponse class

```
class LoginResponse {
  int responseCode;
  String message;
  String responseObject;

  LoginResponse();

  factory LoginResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$LoginResponseFromJson(json);
}
```

[JSON and serialization in Flutter](https://flutter.io/json/)